# Can't call modules in joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a module mod_test:
When using, I call in index.php of templates:

```
<jdoc:include type="module" name="mod_test" />
```

But when run, this module can't show result ? How to fix it ?

Comment: You should not be calling modules directly in the template index.php. index.php should only have module positions. Modules are assigned to a position from the module manager. In order for the position to appear in the drop down list, it must be defined in templateDetails.xml. You can also type a position directly in to the text box to use a position that is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In joomla 1.5 you can using

```
<jdoc:include type="module" name="module name" />
```

I think you check in module mod_test, it can error show data in there

Answer (score 1):

The name attribute references the position on which a module can be called. So you have to define a position give position a name in `templateDetails.xml` and then use the module manager to assign the module mod_test this particular position.

Lets say you have a position left defined in `templatesDetails.xml` then you will have here

`<jdoc:include type="module" name="left" />` and then in your module manager you will go and select your module and assign it position left.

if need more clarification please specify

Answer (score 0):

Modules are rendered on a page using one of the following code example
jdoc:include's name="[template position name]" attribute.
you should give position 
check it! http://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements